# Anaconda not letting me launch Spyder: MacOS

Tags: python, pyqt5, spyder

This is the error I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/anaconda3/bin/spyder", line 11, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 233, in main
from spyder.app import mainwindow
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 42, in 
requirements.check_qt()
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/requirements.py", line 47, in check_qt
if parse_version(actual_ver) File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 121, in parse_version
return packaging.version.Version(v)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/version.py", line 264, in __init__
match = self._regex.search(version)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This problem could be fixed in our latest version (5.3.2). Since it's still not available in Anaconda, please open a new environment and run there these commands: `conda create -n spyder-env -c conda-forge spyder`, `conda activate spyder-env`, `spyder`. That should allow you to use Spyder again.